# How to make a function that creates toggle buttons for a setTimeout loop?

Tags: javascript, button, setinterval, togglebutton

I am trying to create a function that lets me create an on/off toggle button for setTimeout loops and I am having difficulty figuring out how to get this to work the way I want it. The only way I was able to get the loop to stop was by declaring a variable in the global scope that stores the Id value for the setTimeout loop but which defeats the purpose. This also causes an issue if I try to create a second toggle button for a different loop as all the buttons access the same variable. Help would be appreciated. Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainContainer">
        <h1 id='pointA'>Point A</h1>
        <p id='pointB'>Point B</p>
      </div>
</body>
<script>

function createCustomToolbar(){
    
    var myToolbarCustom = document.createElement('div');
    var targetPage= document.querySelector('body');
    var myCSS=myToolbarCustom.style;

    myToolbarCustom.id='myToolbarCustom';
    targetPage.append(myToolbarCustom);

    targetPage.style.padding='transform 0.4s ease';
    targetPage.style.padding='40px';
   
    myCSS.position='fixed';
    myCSS.top=0;
    myCSS.left=0;
    myCSS.width='100%';
    myCSS.height='35px';
    myCSS.border=0;
    myCSS.background='#e3e3e3'
    myCSS.zIndex=9999999;

}
var x;
function toggleCreator(bttnName,callback,targetEle){
    var state=false; 
    var mybttn=document.createElement('button');
    mybttn.className='myCustomTog';
    mybttn.innerHTML=bttnName;
    var bttnTarget=document.getElementById('myToolbarCustom');
    bttnTarget.appendChild(mybttn)
    mybttn.onclick = function() {
        state = !state;
        if (state) {
            mybttn.innerHTML = bttnName + " ON";
            x = callback(targetEle);
        } else {
            mybttn.innerHTML = bttnName + " OFF";
            clearTimeout(x);
        }}

  }

  createCustomToolbar();
  toggleCreator("start",testToggle,document.getElementById('pointA'));
  toggleCreator("start",testToggle,document.getElementById('pointB'));

  
  var i=0;
function testToggle(myTarget){
     x= setTimeout(function(){
        myTarget.innerHTML=i;
        i++;
        testToggle(myTarget);
    },1000)
    
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have multiple buttons and multiple timeOuts (one for each).
I'd create an empty array to store the timeOuts and use x as an index for this array.

```
var x = 0;
var timeouts_arr = [];
```

Inside testToggle...

```
x++;
myTarget.setAttribute('timeout_index', x);
timeouts_arr[x] = setTimeout(function(){...
```

inside mybttn.onclick...

```
state = !state;
if (state) {
      mybttn.innerHTML = bttnName + " ON";
      callback(targetEle); // don't use the x variable here
   } else {
      mybttn.innerHTML = bttnName + " OFF";
      var timeout_index = mybttn.getAttribute('timeout_index');
      clearTimeout(timeout_arr[timeout_index]);
  }}
```